# How to send text input to google assistant sdk in python

Tags: python-3.x, google-assistant-sdk

while converting text to audio and then sending to google assistant pushtalk is not giving accurate result. So i need suggestion, how i can send text data to google assistant textinput to get more accurate result. Or any other suggestion which can increase my accuracy in python

this is what i am currently installed

"pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel \
        google-assistant-library \
        google-assistant-sdk[samples] \
        google-auth-oauthlib[tool]
"

this what i am current using to convert text to audio and then sending to google-assistant

```py
    def post(self):
        args = request.get_json()
        text_received = str(args['assitant_text'])
        file_name = str(args['google_file_name'])
        project_id = str(args['project_id'])
        device_model_id = str(args['device_model_id'])
        refresh_token = str(args['refresh_token'])
        client_id = str(args['client_id'])
        client_secret = str(args['client_secret'])
        voice = str(args['voice'])
        text_received = "WHat is the capital of karnataka"
        logger.emit("Received request parameters from api",
                        {
                            "api": "/google",
                            "args": args
                        }
                    )
        token = {"refresh_token": refresh_token, "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", "client_id": client_id, "client_secret": client_secret, "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype"]}
        with open('credentials.json', 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(token, outfile)
        status = subprocess.call('aws polly synthesize-speech --output-format mp3 --voice-id %s --text "%s"  %s.mp3' %(voice, text_received, file_name), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        logger.emit("Calling aws polly",
                        {
                            "api": "/google",
                            "status_code": status
                        }
                    )
        tf = open("%s.mp3" % file_name, 'r')
        _input = AudioSegment.from_file(tf.name)
        tf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".wav", delete=True)
        output = _input.set_channels(1).set_frame_rate(16000)
        f = output.export(tf.name, format="wav")
        status = subprocess.call('googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk --credentials credentials.json --device-config device_config.json --project-id %s --device-model-id %s -i %s -o %s_output.wav' %(project_id, device_model_id, f.name, file_name), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        logger.emit("Calling google samples assistant pushtotalk",
                        {
                            "api": "/google",
                            "status": status
                        }
                    )
        as_output = AudioSegment.from_file("%s_output.wav" %file_name)

        kf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".wav")
        output = as_output.set_channels(2)
        f = output.export(kf.name, format="wav")
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.AudioFile(f.name) as source:
          output_audio = r.record(source)
        text = r.recognize_google(output_audio)
        f.close()
        kf.close()
        os.remove("%s_output.wav" %file_name)
        os.remove("%s.mp3" %file_name)
        logger.emit("api completed successfully",
                        {
                            "api": "/google",
                            "status": "completed"
                        }
                    )
        return jsonify({"response": text})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send text queries using the API directly instead of trying to convert the audio.

There's also [a sample for text input](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/tree/master/google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/grpc#run-the-samples) that you should be able to access if you download the sample project:

`cd google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/grpc`

`python -m textinput --device-id 'my-device-identifier' --device-model-id 'my-model-identifier'`

Comment: See https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/blob/master/google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/textinput.py#L185

Comment: The link above is the example.

Comment: ```status = subprocess.call('googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk --credentials credentials.json --device-config device_config.json --project-id %s --device-model-id %s -i %s -o %s_output.wav' %(project_id, device_model_id, f.name, file_name), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)``` .    How i can call for textinput in the above way

Comment: You'll have to run the python script directly, as there's no exported name

Comment: You can send a [`text_query`](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/blob/master/google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/textinput.py#L99) instead of an `AudioInConfig`

Comment: Hi @Nick Felker I tried ``` python -m googlesamples.assistant.grpc.textinput --device-id 'abc' --device-model-id 'abc' it is asking me to enter the query using keyboard but for most of the questions i am not getting any answer.

Comment: can you please give me example , where i have to send **text_query** instead of an **AudioInConfig**

Comment: textinput.py doesn't return any response for so many queries like i asked what is the website of shake shack in Newyork ? , what is the address of brookfield mall ?. Its returning NONE for all these queries.

Comment: The `supplemental_display_text` field is not guaranteed to a text response.

Comment: Thanks for your time @Nick Felker. Just one more little help, actually I am getting most of the answer in pushtalk.So can you please suggest me more accurate way of sending text to pushtotalk by converting it into wav file and again converting response to text, So that I can increase accuracy of answers

Comment: There's no good way to convert text and then send it to pushtotalk. You'll get more accuracy just by sending text directly through the textinput.py

Comment: But then I am not getting response from textinput.py for my questions. Basically my task is to ask question about business like what is their average rating, what is their address , Are they open now etc.