# Google assistant textinput

Tags: textinput, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I'm having the same problem as [How to send text input to google assistant sdk in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57901159/how-to-send-text-input-to-google-assistant-sdk-in-python)
I am trying to sent text as an innput using the follwoing command

python -m textinput --device-id XXX-XXX --device-model-id XXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX

However, it doesn't work although pushtotalks works. I ran the above command when I'm in the google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/grpc directory and even outside the directory but still didn't work I keep getting bash: /usr/bin/python3.7.7: No such file or directory

Comment: Do you already have a `credentials.json` file in the folder you're running it from?

Comment: Yes, the credentials.json is at the same folder of textinput.py @NickFelker

Comment: @NickFelker  Is there anything that you can suggest ? Thank you

Comment: It's unclear what file is not being found.

Comment: These are the list of files in the following path /home/pi/assistant-sdk-python/google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/grpc                List of files : credentials.json, device_helper.py, devicetool.py, init.py, pushtotalk.py, readme, requirements.txt and textinput.py   @NickFelker

Comment: That's what I'd expect

Comment: Now the textinput works, but is there a way to have the response as an audio rather than text ? @NickFelker  Thanks

Comment: In the payload you get from textinput, it should include audio data which you can pass to an audio engine to turn into audible sound

Comment: The pushtotalk example shows how to do that

Comment: but If I called textinput.py I only get text. This is the code from textinput file     query = click.prompt('')
            click.echo('<you> %s' % query)
            response_text, response_html = assistant.assist(text_query=query)        @NickFelker

Comment: You can modify that Python file, as the audio response should be included in every response and then you can play that audio response.